# How to cancel selected file with click event in angularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to clear selceted file name on click event of cancel button.

```
 <div class="row">
            <div  class="col-md-5 attribute-labelDiv">
                <div ng-hide="isUploadBtn">
                    <label class="attribute-label">File:</label>
                    <ul>
                        <li>{{fileName}}</li>
                    </ul>
                    <button title="cancel" class="btn btn-primary" type="reset" value="Reset">Cancel</button>
                </div>
</div>
```

How to clear {{fileName}} on click of cancel button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the click event using ng-click directive and reset the variable name

```
<button title="Upload" ng-click="reset()" class="btn btn-primary" type="reset" value="Reset">Cancel</button>
```

Controller.js

```
$scope.reset = function(){
  $scope.fileName = '';
}
```

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
$scope.fileName = "sample";
 $scope.reset = function(){
  $scope.fileName = "";
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<ul>
    <li>{{fileName}}</li>
</ul>
 <button ng-show="fileName" title="cancel" ng-click="fileName = '';" class="btn btn-primary" type="reset" value="Reset">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Comment: can I hide button also after clicking on it.

Comment: it is working.but when I select another file to attach,file is not getting.

Comment: It depends on the logic you use! provide more detail to the question

Comment: this is for select file and upload.If user by mistake drag wrong file into the box and now he want to remove that file.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use this `ng-click` like this

```
 <button title="cancel" ng-click="fileName = ''" class="btn btn-primary" type="reset" value="Reset">Cancel</button>
```

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

$scope.fileName = "same text"

 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
<ul>
    <li>{{fileName}}</li>
</ul>
 <button ng-init="btnShow = true" title="cancel" ng-show="btnShow" ng-click="fileName = '';btnShow = false;" class="btn btn-primary" type="reset" value="Reset">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to  hide button also after clicking  on it.

Comment: @Ashish check the demo again

Comment: getting error-"Angular-auto-validate: invalid bs3 form structure elements must be wrapped by a form-group class"